# pip broken on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS after updating it

Tags: python-2.7, pip, setuptools

After updating `pip` I now see the following error logs. How can I fix it? I'm using Python 2.7.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3013, in <module>
@_call_aside
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2999, in _call_aside
f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3026, in _initialize_master_working_set
working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 657, in _build_master
return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 670, in _build_from_requirements
dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 849, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==7.1.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Comment: How did you update pip? Via `apt-get update`?

Comment: I have used this command after that it is stop working.                                                        `pip install -U setuptools pip`

Answer (score 1):

I have solve it by following process.

1st : 
Download the `pip 7.1.0 version` and extract it to the following path

```
usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources
```

2nd : 
Give the executable permission to the python 2.7 directory using following command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 python2.7/
```

then if I use `pip -V` command to check pip version, it is showing me version 7.1.0 without any error log.

Comment: Note that you've made the directory world writable, which is a terrible idea.